# Select from Select

Tags: sql

Hello I have a vehicle inspection database here and I have a code in sql that gives me 2nd and succeeding EventTime or greater than Min(EventTime) with corresponding TicketStatus. Tables are [Event] and [Car]... [Event] table have fields CarID (FK); EventTime; TicketStatus... While on the [Car] table have fields CarID (PK); PlateNo; Package

Note: [Car].CarID data type is unique identifier Ex. {16F0151E-1938-4487-BB75-FF446B4DB7FF}

Executing the code will give me the CarID, EventTime, TicketStatus. I dont want the CarID as the result, i want the PlateNo from table [Car], TicketStatus, EventTime AND the criteria [Car].Package = 4

```
SELECT CarID, TicketStatus, [EventTime]  
FROM 
  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY [EventTime] ASC) AS [index]
       , CarID, TicketStatus, [EventTime] 
   FROM vehicle.dbo.Event Event) A  
 WHERE [index] > 1
```

Comment: sorry to say but your question is not clear at all.Can you provide some sample data and desired output?

Comment: "I'm getting errors" has absolutely no meaning unless to tell us what "errors" means. What "errors" are you getting specifically? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is the **exact** error message? You have that information, and if you don't share it with us we can't help you. We can't see your screen from where we are, and if you want our help you need to provide the details that allow us to help you.

Comment: Provide sample data for both tables in a tabular form

Comment: The code actually gives me the result i want which is vehicles that was inspected greater than the Min(EventTime) or it gives me the succeeding events after the first inspection with TicketStatus. The problem on the code is the CarID which is the primary key for the [Car] table instead of Plate number. So when i generate this code it will give me something like this colums and datas - CARID:                                          A57D4151-BD49-4B44-AF10-000F1C298E05 ; TicketStatus: 0 ; EventTime: 2013-03-30 13:55:26.187

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want you just need to `JOIN` with `Car` table like this

```
SELECT c.PlateNo, TicketStatus, EventTime 
  FROM 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY EventTime) AS rnum
       , CarID, TicketStatus, EventTime
   FROM Event
) a JOIN Car c
   ON a.CarID = c.CarID  
 WHERE c.Package = 4
   AND a.rnum > 1
```

or

```
SELECT PlateNo, TicketStatus, EventTime
  FROM 
(
  SELECT e.CarID, e.TicketStatus, e.EventTime, c.PlateNo,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY e.CarID ORDER BY e.EventTime) AS rnum 
    FROM Event e JOIN Car c 
      ON e.CarID = c.CarID 
   WHERE c.Package = 4
) a
 WHERE a.rnum > 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/507e5/10)** demo